# Grab raw HTML from external file (trusted)

Tags: angularjs

I am using an Angular directive to output content from a JSON file, and need to use the content in that JSON to also find and output raw HTML from an external file (read from a file.)

Here is my directive code:

```
app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);

app.directive('patterns', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^ngType',
        scope: {
            ngType: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'patterns.html',
        controller: function($scope, $http, $sce) {
            var theType = $scope.ngType;
            $http.get('indexes/json/' + theType + '.json')
                .then(function(result) {
                    $scope.patterns = result.data;
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'patterns'
    }
});
```

Here is my template:

```
<div class="pattern">
    <iframe src="{{ 'individuals/' + pattern.anchor + '/index.html'}}" frameborder="0" id="frame_{{pattern.id}}" class="frame-mobile" />
    <!-- Code view -->
    <div class="pattern__code">
        <div>
        <pre class="pattern__code--markup">
            <code class="language-markup line-numbers" ng-bind-html="'patterns/' + pattern.anchor + '.html' | to_trusted" prism></code>
        </pre> 
        </div>
        <div>
        <pre class="pattern__code--css">
            <code class="language-scss line-numbers" ng-include="'individuals/' + pattern.anchor + '/scss/_' + pattern.anchor + '.scss'" prism></code>
        </pre> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example JSON file I would pull from:

```
[
    {
        "id": "lists", 
        "anchor": "lists", 
        "title": "Lists", 
        "description": "",
        "guidelines": "", 
        "updated": "2015-08-17"
    }
]
```

I am able to pull in the pattern as rendered HTML fine. For the code view, the CSS loads fine because it's treated as text. The HTML however, does not render as I believe the HTML needs to be encoded.

This leads me to believe I should be reading the file in the controller itself, except I am not sure how to add to my existing directive/controller to access pattern.anchor so that each iteration of the template will:

1. Read the file from the appropriate path (patterns/ = pattern.anchor + .html)
2. encode the HTML and "trust" it
3. Output the raw HTML into the appropriate `<code>` element

What am I missing? Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqXASrV5mB6mqwxhWHoU

Comment: Yep avoid `ng-include` as it's for embedding HTML nodes into the DOM. What you want is get your plain HTML wit a regular $http call and bind it directly with a `ng-bind`. If you want some formatting and syntax highlight for the output HTML you can search for a code editor such as CodeMirror.

Comment: I'm handling code highlighting with prism which isn't a problem. Just unsure how to incorporate the $http call into my current controller?

Comment: I'm not sure about all the formats of your jsons but basically when `$http.get('indexes/json/' + theType + '.json')` returns the url you can chain  another `$http.get` (or add it into the `then` callback) on the url and put the result in your scope.